# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Волк послушался. Более прагматичный, заяц решил действовать иначе"?

Мне кажется, что нужна. Иначе получится нелепая фраза "более прагматичный заяц", будто присутствует и менее прагматичный.
Но есть ли правило?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фраза не так уж и нелепа, вполне корректна, вовсе не обязательно иметь в виду менее прагматичного зайца, ясно, что речь о разных представителях лесных жителей. Запятая нужна в том случае, если автор подчёркивает причинное значение: "будучи прагматичным". Если не подчёркивает (при чтении не выделяет паузой) - запятая не нужна. Выбор за автором.

Answer (score 2):

Мне тоже кажется, что заяц вполне может быть более прагматичным... чем кто угодно.))) А вот и правило, о котором говорила Людмила: 
Обособляются определения, стоящие перед определяемым словом, если они имеют добавочные обстоятельственные значения.
Это могут быть как распространенные, так и одиночные определения, стоящие непосредственно перед определяемым существительным, если они имеют добавочное обстоятельственное значение (причинное, условное, уступительное и т.д.). В подобных случаях определительный оборот легко заменяется придаточным предложением причины с союзом потому что, придаточным предложением условия с союзом если, придаточным уступки с союзом хотя.
Для проверки наличия обстоятельственного значения можно использовать замену определительного оборота оборотом со словом будучи: если такая замена возможна, то определение обособляется. Например: 
Сильно заболевшая, мать не могла ходить на работу.
(добавочное значение причины)
Даже заболевшая, мать ходила на работу
(добавочное значение уступки)

Так что это просто обособленное согласованное распространенное определение (а не что-то вроде приложения, как я подумала сначала).

Answer (score 1):

Запятую здесь можно поставить только при ооочень большом желании. И долго-долго обосновывать. А вообще-то она не нужна. А заяц более прагматичный, чем медведь, а не чем другой заяц.

ЗЫ О, бог ты мой... Не медведь, а волк! )))